# How to import a modern.ie vm into Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, modern.ie

I'm trying [modern.IE](http://www.modern.ie/) for the first time. The instructions say to download the vm for the appropriate OS (which I have done).  Then to extract the exe/rar files.  Then to import the vm.  I opened hyper-v manager, clicked Import Virtual Machine, selected the Virtual Machine directory that resulted from the extraction but when I click next I get an error that no virtual machines exist at that location.

Anyone have any ideas?  Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't select the Virtual Machines directory - go back one level.  The folder you want should contain a file called config.xml.

Alternately, forget about importing the VM configuration.  You can create a new VM and just attach the VHD file to it.

Comment: I do have config.xml one directory above but I get the same error.

Comment: It might be easier to just create a new VM and attach the VHD from modern.ie to it instead of bothering with the import.

Comment: Ok.  I wasn't sure if that would preserve all of the settings, etc.  That seems to have worked.

Comment: @mikekol if you update your answer with the contents of your comment then I'll mark it as the answer.